# R how to replace only consecutive duplicated values in a column after group_by

Tags: r, group-by, duplicates

In the following dataframe with 2 columns, How can we replace only the consecutive Duplicated values in second column by grouping by first

```
df <- data.frame(A = c( 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3),
                 B = c(100,100,200,100,200,200,200,300,300,200))
```

here for the group 3, it will be `200, NA, 300, NA, 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, B := ifelse(duplicated(rleid(B)), NA, B), by = "A"]
df
#>     A   B
#>  1: 1 100
#>  2: 1  NA
#>  3: 1 200
#>  4: 2 100
#>  5: 2 200
#>  6: 3 200
#>  7: 3  NA
#>  8: 3 300
#>  9: 3  NA
#> 10: 3 200
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can replace with `duplicated` and `ave`

```
df$B <-  with(df, ave(B, A, FUN = function(x) 
      replace(x, duplicated(with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))), NA)))

df$B
#[1] 100  NA 200 100 200 200  NA 300  NA 200
```